# matching multiple lines with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression: `<!.*->`

It matches text A but not text B. Why is that? The only difference to me is that text B is a block.

text A:

```
<!-- name of register file -->
```

text B:

```
<!--  codes
        ''   - no level
        SITE - site level 
        ACCT - acct level 
        PLCY - policy level 
-->
```

I am using this website to test: http://regexpal.com/.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, I'm using http://regexpal.com/.  I think it's javascript regex.